# VB.net deleting a record but stills shows in database access file

Tags: database, vb.net

I have created a database file in MS access and linked to vb.net form. When i delete a record at run time it shows deleted in user interface but when i checked the Database file its stills in DB file what should i do ?

I have used this function

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    StudentData1BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub
```

Comment: Add StudentDataBindingSource.DataBind() after what you have there...

Comment: Dear there is no function named with DataBind() function in StudentDataBindingSource

Comment: It's deleting from the client - you need to delete from the DB. Do you have a DeleteCommand on the datasource?

Comment: How did you populate the BindingSource? using a datatable? if yes removing the current entity will only remove that record from the datatable, you need to persist the change to the datatable with a dataadapter

Comment: @Talhakhankhalil Go to your dataset design and create a query for deletion then use it in your save button code.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving after you remove the record. Should look something like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    StudentData1BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    Me.Validate()
    Me.StudentData1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.StudentData1DataSet)
End Sub
```